# Creating a Nested List using for loops

Tags: tuples, nested-lists, python-itertools

This is related to a homework problem for an Inverse Theory Programming class:

We are given a small dataset with x and y values:

```
x     y  
----  ---- 
0.5   1.2            
1     1.8            
1.5   1.7            
2     3              
2.5   3.5            
3     3.2            
3.5   4.5            
4     4.8            
4.5   5.3            
5     6.2
```

```
xdata = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0]
ydata = [1.2, 1.8, 1.7, 3.0, 3.5, 3.2, 4.5, 4.8, 5.3, 6.2]
```

The ultimate goal to find the best fit line for said data using a grid searching technique. The following code produces a grid with m and b values (y=mx+b).

```
   gridm = np.linspace(0.4,0.8,10)
   gridb = np.linspace(-1,1,10)

   def makegrid(dim1, dim2):
       return list(itertools.product(dim1,dim2))

   grid = makegrid(gridm,gridb)
```

itertools.product returns a tuple list with an m and b value. I want to take every m and b pair in the grid and calculate a y-value for every x-value in xdata. I use a for loop to iterate over every pair in the grid but manually define the x-values in data:

```
def linear(m,x,b):
    y = (m*x)+b
    return y

ypred = []
ypred1 = []
ypred2 = []
for i,j in grid: 
    ypred1.append(linear(i,xdata[0],j))
    ypred2.append(linear(i,xdata[1],j))
    ypred = [ypred1,ypred2]
```

Instead I would like to iterate over the xdata, which I believe is something like this:

```
    ypred = []
    for i,j in grid: 
        for k in xdata: 
            yb = linear(i,k,j)
                ypred.append(yb)
```

this returns a list:
[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,etc]

I would like create a nested list which contains all calculated y-values from the tuples in grid for each x-value in xdata. In other words I am looking for something like this:

```
lst = [[m1*x1+b1, m1*x1+b2, m1*x1+b3, ..., m4*x1+b1... ], [m1*x2+b1, m1*x2+b2, m1*x2+b3, ...,      m4*x2+b1...], [m1*x3+b1, m1*x3+b2, m1*x3+b3, ..., m4*x3+b1...], etc ]
```

where,
xdata = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,etc]

Thanks.

Note: ypred returns something that looks like lst, I would really like to know how to do this iteratively with for loops

Comment: These seem like inconvenient identifiers: `for i, j in grid:`. Wouldn't you find it preferable to use `for m, b ...` ? Also, we're looking at the first two `xdata` values, but it's not clear why we're ignoring the remainder of them.

Comment: The goal is to iterate over all xdata values, im not ignoring the rest.